# TCP-IP Communication via Python and an open port of a SSH connection

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, ssh

This is a newbie question for TCP-based communication in Python. I am trying to establish a TCP-based communication between two *NIX systems via an SSH tunnel and the Python socket module. I have used the two first examples "echo server" and "echo client" from this Python MOTW website: http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/socket/tcp.html.

The communication worked fine on the same *NIX system (HOST1) but failed over the ssh tunnel.

I logged into the second *NIX system with `ssh -L 10000:HOST2:10000 USERNAME@HOST2`. Then I played around and tried to establish the communication in the same manner by starting the python script for the server on HOST2 and the script for the client on HOST1. This I got on stderr:

```
python test_socket_client.py 
connecting to localhost port 10000
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test_socket_client.py", line 10, in <module>
sock.connect(server_address)
File "<string>", line 1, in connect
socket.error: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

When I started server and client vice versa on HOST1 and HOST2, respectively, I got the same message.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Your server binds its socket to localhost:10000 -- which means it listens to connections from the loopback interface only.  The SSH command line instructs SSH to tunnel local connections to port 10000 to connections to HOST2:10000.  Your client Python program connects to localhost:10000, and the remote end of the SSH link then tries to connect to HOST2:10000.  Even though that's the same port and the same machine as your socket is bound to, it's a different interface, to which your socket is not listening.

Change the SSH command line to `ssh -L 10000:localhost:10000 USERNAME@HOST2`, or bind your server's listening socket to all interfaces: `server_address = ('', 10000)`.  The empty string serves as INADDR_ANY.

Of course, what Gary van der Merwe said is true: SSH would need to be running at the time you run your client Python program on HOST1.

Answer (score 0):

I would check that your server is listening on the server host, and that the ssh client is listening on the client host. You can run `netstat -tnlp` to check this.

Are you sure that your ssh client is still open when you are running your client. You either need to run shh in one terminal, and your client in another, or run `ssh -Nf` which causes ssh to go to the background after it has authenticated.